# Global optimum of sum of convex functions

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Take two real differentiable convex functions, $f_1$ and $f_2$, defined on the unit interval $[0, 1]$. I want to find the global optimum of

$$\min_{x \in [0,1]} a f_1(x) + b f_2(x)$$

for given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: It's probably easier to answer if a and b are nonnegative, since $af_1(x)+bf_2(x)$ is convex when $a>0$ and $b>0$.

Comment: Just to add to Snowball's answer more explicitly, if a or b are negative then convexity is not guaranteed so in general it will be difficult to optimize.

Comment: Moreover, if $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative and $f_1$ and $f_2$ have their global minima at $s$ and $t$, then $f = a f_1 + b f_2$ has a global minimum somewhere in the interval $[\min(s,t),\max(s,t)]$.

Comment: To expand on @Bitwise's comment: any $C^2$ function on $[0,1]$ can be written as the difference of two $C^2$ convex functions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks Robert, I wasn't aware of that. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Write $f''$ as the sum between its non-negative part and its non-positive part and integrate twice...